# Start may not be called on a promise-style task. exception is coming

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I am creating a simple wpf desktop application. UI have just a button and code in .cs file like.

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FunctionA();
}

public void FunctionA()
{
    Task.Delay(5000).Start();
    MessageBox.Show("Waiting Complete");
}
```

But surprisingly line `Task.Delay(5000).Start();` is throwing an `InvalidOperationException`:

> Start may not be called on a promise-style task.

Can any one help why it is like this?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

You are getting that error because the `Task` class already started the task before giving it to you.  You should only ever call `Start` on a task that you create by calling its constructor, and you shouldn't even do that unless you have a compelling reason to not start the task when you create it; if you want it started right away you should use `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` to both create and start a new `Task`.

So, now we know to just get rid of that pesky `Start`.  You'll run your code and find that the message box is shown right away, not 5 seconds later, what's up with that?

Well, `Task.Delay` just gives you a task that will be completed in 5 seconds.  It doesn't stop execution of the thread for 5 seconds.  What you want to do is have some code that's executed after that task finishes.  That's what `ContinueWith` is for.  It lets you run some code after a given task is done:

```
public void FunctionA()
{
    Task.Delay(5000)
    .ContinueWith(t => 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Waiting Complete");
    });
}
```

This will behave as expected.

We could also leverage C# 5.0's `await` keyword to add continuations more easily:

```
public async Task FunctionA()
{
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    MessageBox.Show("Waiting Complete");
}
```

While a full explanation of what's going on here is beyond the scope of this question, the end result is a method that behaves very similar to the previous method; it will show a message box 5 seconds after you call the method, but the method itself will return [almost] right away in both cases.  That said, `await` is very powerful, and allows us to write methods that seem simple and straightforward, but that would be much harder and messier to write using `ContinueWith` directly.  It also greatly simplifies dealing with error handling, taking out a lot of boilerplate code.