# Executing a function at a later time

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I have the following code whose purpose is to call a function at a specific time. However I get the exception when `WaitTask.Start();` is called `Additional information: Start may not be called on a promise-style task.`

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime twoThirtyET = today.AddHours(14.50);

Execute(CallAtTime, twoThirtyET);

public void Execute(Action action, DateTime ExecutionTime)
{
    Task WaitTask =          Task.Delay((int)ExecutionTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
    WaitTask.ContinueWith(_ => action);
    WaitTask.Start();
}

private void CallAtTime()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Called at time");
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just create a console app that does what you want NOW and schedule it via Windows Scheduler or some other scheduling tool?

Comment: First answer that found by searching for error message https://www.bing.com/search?q=Additional+information%3A+Start+may+not+be+called+on+a+promise-style+task seem to provide almost exact code you trying to write (short of computing time that you know how to do) in both styles (`async` and `ContinueWith`) - so looks perfect duplicate. Note that as @DStanley pointed out there are better more reliable ways to achieve scheduling of tasks unless it is exactly what you want to learn.

Comment: To be fair, there might be scenarios where the Windows Scheduler is not appropriate. Cache invalidation is the only terrible example I can think of at the moment.

Comment: @TroelsLarsen sure. Also in most cases there would be existing solution that handles that better than custom code that may run at some point. I.e. for your sample - most caching frameworks have expiration timeouts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `Additional information: Start may not be called on a promise-style task.` because the `Task` from `Task.Delay` has already been started, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15167248/921321) for further information.

The simplest change to make would be to remove the call to `WaitTask.StartNew()` as it is unnecessary.

Oh, and you may want to actually invoke your action in the callback rather than just returning it:

```
WaitTask.ContinueWith(_ => action());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a timer. (2000 is the interval in milliseconds, so 2 seconds)

```
class Program
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer _timer;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        _timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        _timer.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop(); //If you only want it to run once
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Full Example**

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    using System.Threading;

    public class MainClass
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            PostponedAction action = new PostponedAction();
            action.WaitExecute(DateTime.Today.AddHours(14.5) - DateTime.Now);
        }
    }

    public class PostponedAction
    {
        public void WaitExecute(TimeSpan waitTime)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(waitTime);
            // Do stuff
        }
    }
}
```