# Running Tasks in parallel

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

I am failing to understand why this doesn't seem to run the tasks in Parallel:

```
var tasks = new Task<MyReturnType>[mbis.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
{
     tasks[i] = CAS.Service.GetAllRouterInterfaces(mbis[i], 3);
}

Parallel.ForEach(tasks, task => task.Start());
```

By stepping through the execution, I see that as soon as this line is evaluated:

```
tasks[i] = CAS.Service.GetAllRouterInterfaces(mbis[i], 3);
```

The task starts.  I want to add all the new tasks to the list, and then execute them in parallel.

Comment: Don't return "Cold Tasks" fix `GetAllRouterInterfaces` and make it return running tasks (or are they running already, its hard to tell from your question).

Comment: If `GetAllRouterInterfaces` is an `async` method returning a `Task` it should most likely be called `GetAllRouterInterfacesAsync`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `GetAllRouterInterfaces` is an `async` method, the resulting `Task` will already be started (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15167248/921321) for further explanation).

This means that `tasks` will contain multiple tasks all of which are running in parallel without the subsequent call to `Parallel.ForEach`.

You may wish to wait for all the entries in `tasks` to complete, you can do this with an `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`.

So you should end up with:

```
var tasks = new Task<MyReturnType>[mbis.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = CAS.Service.GetAllRouterInterfaces(mbis[i], 3);
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

**Update from comments**

It seems that despite `GetAllRouterInterfaces` being `async` and returning a `Task` it is still making synchronous POST requests (presumably before any other `await`). This would explain why you are getting minimal concurrency as each call to `GetAllRouterInterfaces` is blocking while this request is made. The ideal solution would be to make an aynchronous POST request, e.g:

```
await webclient.PostAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

This will ensure your `for` loop is not blocked and the requests are made concurrently.

**Further update after conversation**

It seems you are unable to make the POST requests asynchronous and `GetAllRouterInterfaces` does not actually do any asynchronous work, due to this I have advised the following:

1. Remove `async` from `GetAllRouterInterfaces` and change the return type to `MyReturnType`
2. Call `GetAllRouterInterfaces` in parallel like so

   ```
   var routerInterfaces = mbis.AsParallel()
       .Select(mbi => CAS.Service.GetAllRouterInterfaces(mbi, 3));
   ```

Comment: GetAllRouterInterfaces returns a Task<>, and it does start doing things right away.  For some reason, I am not seeing a benefit in time savings when I am running them in parallel vs. doing them one by one.

Also, is there a different between Tasks.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray) and await Task.WhenAll(tasks)?

Comment: @blgrnboy just because you run something in parallel does not mean it will be faster, especially if they are all trying to share a single resource like a disk or a server.

Comment: @blgrnboy, `Task.WaitAll()` is blocking. It will block thread until all tasks have finished.

Comment: As @ScottChamberlain says, not everything will be benefited by running in parallel, your `GetAllRouterInterface` may have something blocking or be bottlenecked. `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` should be used in `async` methods whereas `Task.WaitAll` is for synchronous methods and will block the calling thread.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yeah, I understand that part.  They are all making REST calls, but I would assume at least some reduction in time, being that the resource is pretty heavily hit by others and doesn't typically slow down.

Comment: I don't want to sidetrack the question too much but if you update your question with the contents of `GetAllRouterInterfaces` and the code which makes the `REST` call it may reveal something.

Comment: I don't want to post all of that, but I will say this.  GetAllRouterInterfaces is not necessarily parallel itself, it will generate some XmlContent, a make an HTTP Post with it.  I was under the impression that as long as the calling method was trying to call this in parallel, it didn't matter what how the called method executed its work.

Comment: Is your HTTP post being made asynchronously, like `await webclient.PostAsync(request)`? There are many ways to perform work in parallel but as `async` methods start immediately you could be blocking your `for` loop with each invocation of `GetAllRouterInterfaces` limiting the amount of concurrency.

Comment: No, unfortunately, that is not being make asynchronously :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104589/discussion-between-lukazoid-and-blgrnboy).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand you the right way.

First of all, if **GetAllRouterInterfaces** is returns a Task you have to await the result.

With Parallel.ForEach you can't await tasks like as it is, but you can do something similar like this:

```
public async Task RunInParallel(IEnumerable<TWhatEver> mbisItems)
{
    //mbisItems == your parameter that you want to pass to GetAllRouterInterfaces

    //degree of cucurrency
    var concurrentTasks = 3;

    //Parallel.Foreach does internally something like this:
    await Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(mbisItems).GetPartitions(concurrentTasks)
        select Task.Run(async delegate
        {
            using (partition)
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                {
                    var currentMbis = partition.Current;
                    var yourResult = await GetAllRouterInterfaces(currentMbis,3);
                }
        }
       ));
}
```