# RestSharp - How to return a hot task?

Tags: c#, async-await, restsharp

I have a WinForms app and in that app I have a repository class, Collections, that makes calls to a restful service using RestSharp.  The repository code is similar to this...

```
public Task<IRestResponse<List<CollectionDto>>> GetCollectionsPagedAsync()
{
    var client = RestClientFactory.Create();
    var request = new RestRequest("api/collections");

    // Parameters omitted for brevity

    return client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List<CollectionDto>>(request);
}
```

What I *thought* would happen is that this would kick off the service operation and immediately return a task.  Then, while the service operation was working the front end would be free to perform other operations.  After those were finished it would `await` the task.  So the front end would be similar to...

```
var repository = new CollectionRepository();
var getCollectionsTask = repository.GetCollectionsPagedAsync();

// Do other initialization work here

// If the collections task hasn't completed, wait it out...    
var collectionList = await getCollectionsTask;
```

I put a breakpoint in my service operation and tested this code.  The call to ExecuteTaskAsync does not cause the breakpoint to be hit.  Only when I execute the await does the operation actually start running.

I'm fairly new to async in C# but it appears that RestSharp is giving me back a "cold task."  I can't call `Start` on the task myself or I get "Start may not be called on a promise-style task."  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230372/start-may-not-be-called-on-a-promise-style-task-exception-is-coming) SO thread...

> You are getting that error because the Task class already started the
>   task before giving it to you.

So I'm stumped.  The absence of a breakpoint hit (and other tests) suggests I have a cold task, the error message suggests I have a hot task.  So what is the correct way to consume a restful service in an async manner?

Comment: put `var init = Task.Run(()=> {/*Do other initialization work here*/});`  then use `await Task.WhenAll(getCollectionsTask, init); var collectionList = getCollectionsTask.Result;` ... it would run both task in parallel (if can)

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/L0pehY