# How to compose a unit test if a task is followed by task.start()?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

In program, we have:

```
var task1 = some task;
task1.start()
```

If mock the task result in unit test, the result is returned by mock mechanism immediately before calling the start(), and raise "Start may not be called on a task that has completed" exception.

How to address that issue and compose a valid unit test?

Paste a simplified sample code here for clarity, which produces the above exception:

```
namespace TestTaskStart
{
    public class TestMethods : ITestMethods
    {
        public async Task<int> AlwaysReturnOne(int number)
        {
            return await Task.FromResult(1);
        }
    }
}

namespace TestTaskStart {
    public class TestInvoker
    {
        private ITestMethods testMethods;

        public TestInvoker(ITestMethods testMethods)
        {
            this.testMethods = testMethods;
        }

        public async Task<int> GetANumberWrapperTask(int number)
        {
            // just an exmple of one tasks to be called
            var task = this.testMethods.AlwaysReturnOne(number);
            task.Start();
            Task.WaitAll(task);

            return task.Result;
        }
    }
}

namespace TestTaskStart {
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTests
    {
        ITestMethods numberGetter;
        TestInvoker testInvoker;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Setup()
        {
            this.numberGetter = Substitute.For<ITestMethods>();
            this.testInvoker = new TestInvoker(this.numberGetter);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void TestGetANumberWrapper()
        {
            this.MockAlwaysReturnOneResult();
            var result = testInvoker.GetANumberWrapperTask(5).Result;
        }

        private void MockAlwaysReturnOneResult()
        {
            this.numberGetter.AlwaysReturnOne(Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you replace the *"some task"* with your actual code?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias thanks for the comment, append a simplified sample project to the post, have verified it locally with same exception.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Start may not be called on a promise-style task. exception is coming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230372/start-may-not-be-called-on-a-promise-style-task-exception-is-coming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Task.Start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start) method can only be called on "cold" tasks, in other words on tasks that have not been started yet. Such tasks can only be created with the `Task` constructor. Tasks created by invoking asynchronous methods implemented with the `async` keyword are "hot", in other words they are already started upon creation. From the docs:

> **Exceptions**
> `InvalidOperationException`
> The `Task` is not in a valid state to be started. It may have already been started, executed, or canceled, or it may have been created in a manner that doesn't support direct scheduling.

This is also a good reading: [A Tour of Task, Part 10: Promise Tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2015/04/a-tour-of-task-part-10-promise-tasks.html)